# Laravel service provider not binding to contract

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have below contract/interface which is binded by a service provider ,however the i get below error :

> ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81:
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\RocketShipContract does not exist

What am i doing wrong ?

**Contract**

```
namespace App\Contracts\Helpers;

Interface RocketShipContract
{

    public function blastOff();


}
```

**The concrete class**

```
namespace app\Contracts;

use App\Contracts\Helpers\RocketShipContract;

class RocketShip implements RocketShipContract
{

    public function blastOff()
    {

        return 'Houston, we have ignition';

    }

}
```

**The service provider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Contracts\RocketShip;

class RocketShipServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\Helpers\RocketShipContract', function($app){

            return new  App\Contracts\RocketShip($app['HttpClient']);

        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return ['App\Contracts\Helpers\RocketShipContract'];
    }

}
```

**The controller**

```
public function test(RocketShipContract $rocketship)
    {
         $boom = $rocketship->blastOff();

        return view('test.index', compact('boom'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting hints at the problem: the class is being resolved in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. That's because you need to specify the full namespace of your interface in the controller.

So either include it with a `use` statement:

```
use App\Contracts\Helpers\RocketShipContract;
```

Or type hint the full namespace:

```
public function test(App\Contracts\Helpers\RocketShipContract $rocketship)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The interface is now beign called i however get this error now `Target [App\Helpers\Contracts\RocketShipContract] is not instantiable.`

Comment: Is your `RocketShipServiceProvider` added to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`?